# Perl : How to extract unique entries of a text file

Tags: perl, bigdata, duplicates

I am totally a beginner in Perl. I have a large file (around 100 G) which looks like this:

```
 domain, ip
 "www.google.ac.",173.194.33.111
 "www.google.ac.",173.194.33.119
 "www.google.ac.",173.194.33.120
 "www.google.ac.",173.194.33.127
 "www.google.ac.",173.194.33.143
 "apple.com., 173.194.33.143
 "studio.com.", 173.194.33.143
 "www.google.ac.",101.78.156.201
 "www.google.ac.",101.78.156.201
```

So basically I have 1-duplicate lines, 2- one ip with different domains, 3- one domain with different ips. and I would like to remove the duplicate lines from the file (the ones with same domain,ip pair).

**I have already reviewed other answers in regards to the same question, none of them address my problem with large files .

Does anybody have a clue how can I do it in PERL? or any suggestion for more optimal language?

Comment: Deduping is usually done with a hash, since hash keys are unique.

Comment: Have you tried using `uniq`?

Comment: @TLP do you mean bash uniq? my files are not sorted which makes the process last long I guess

Comment: You will have the same problem in Perl.

Comment: You've tagged your question with `bigdata`, so you probably know about Hadoop, right? It'd be feasible in Hadoop, even with Perl-based mappers

Comment: @mpapec - this question is not about a duplicates removal in Perl, it is about the duplicates removal in large text files. So, I think, your reference to the previously answered question doesn't help much in this case.

Comment: @HEKTO here you go..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is read the file a line at a time and use each line as the key of a hash.  You have to have memory to store each unique line once, though.  There's no getting around that.

Here's a one-liner as run from the shell:

```
perl -ne '$lines{$_}++; END { print keys %lines }' filename
```